# Make div a percentage height of sibling div

Tags: html, css

I want the heights of all of the different bars to be percentages of the height of bar seven. So when the height of bar seven incrases or decreases, the height of the other bars would increase/decrease in scale with it.

So is there a way to tie the height of the bars to barseven? Or would I have to use JS to achieve this? So far I have the following codes

```css
.barcontainer {
  height: 100px;
}

.bar {
  position: relative;
  width: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #404b57;
  height: 5px;
  /* border-bottom: 3px solid #fff; */
  background-color: #404b57;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.1s, margin 0.1s;
  -moz-transition: height 0.1s, margin 0.1s;
  -ms-transition: height 0.1s, margin 0.1s;
  transition: height 0.1s, margin 0.1s;
}


/* This is for the starting state at which point they all just need to be the same height */

.barone,
.bartwo,
.barthree,
.barfour,
.barfive,
.barsix,
.barseven,
.bareight,
.barnine,
.barten,
.bareleven,
.bartwelve,
.barthirteen {
  height: 5px;
  margin: 47.5px 0 47.5px 0;
}

.loud .barseven {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.loud .barsix,
.loud .bareight {
  height: 90%;
  margin: 5% 0 5% 0;
}

.loud .barfive,
.loud .barnine {
  height: 70%;
  margin: 15% 0 15% 0;
}

.loud .barfour,
.loud .barten {
  height: 45%;
  margin: 27.5% 0 27.5% 0;
}

.loud .barthree,
.loud .bareleven {
  height: 20%;
  margin: 40% 0 40% 0;
}

.loud .bartwo,
.loud .bartwelve {
  height: 10%;
  margin: 45% 0 45% 0;
}

.loud .barone,
.loud .barthirteen {
  height: 5%;
  margin: 47.5% 0 47.5% 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="audiomode">
  <div class="barcontainer loud">
    <div class="bar barone"></div>
    <div class="bar bartwo"></div>
    <div class="bar barthree"></div>
    <div class="bar barfour"></div>
    <div class="bar barfive"></div>
    <div class="bar barsix"></div>
    <div class="bar barseven"></div>
    <div class="bar bareight"></div>
    <div class="bar barnine"></div>
    <div class="bar barten"></div>
    <div class="bar bareleven"></div>
    <div class="bar bartwelve"></div>
    <div class="bar barthirteen"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the `.barseven`'s height changes dynamically or it has an initial value that doesn't get updated ?

Comment: The height of .barseven would be being updated dynamically.

Comment: At first thought, you may use a `CSS` variable that contains the initial height and then use that variable as `barseven`'s height then, instead of changing the height directly, you just update that variable.

Comment: Yes that's a great idea! Thanks!

Comment: You're gladly welcome. Feel free to ask for any further assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made variable which is `value` once you change the value the height of both `master` `div` and `slave` `div` and you can change the difference between `master` and `slave` by modifying their height on the CSS for me I made `master` two times of its `slave`

```js
let value = 40;
let master = document.getElementById('master');
let slave = document.getElementById('slave');
let masterHeight = master.style.setProperty('--x', value + 'px');
let slaveHeight = slave.style.setProperty('--x', value + 'px');
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div {
  margin: 10px;
  background: darkcyan;
  width: 20px;
}

#master {
  height: calc(var(--x));
}

#slave {
  height: calc(var(--x) * 2);
}
```

```html
<div id="master"></div>
<div id="slave"></div>
```

I and here it's an output where I change the value of the variable `value` and you see that both increases their height

```js
let value = 100;
let master = document.getElementById('master');
let slave = document.getElementById('slave');
let masterHeight = master.style.setProperty('--x', value + 'px');
let slaveHeight = slave.style.setProperty('--x', value + 'px');
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div {
  margin: 10px;
  background: darkcyan;
  width: 20px;
}

#master {
  height: calc(var(--x));
}

#slave {
  height: calc(var(--x) * 2);
}
```

```html
<div id="master"></div>
<div id="slave"></div>
```

Comment: I didn't use this excatly but this answer helped me realised I could use flexbox so thank you for that!